# laravel authorization @can directive always fails

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-5.1

I am trying to implement authorization in Laravel, following [this guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization).

**SubscriptionPolicy**:

```
public function manage($user) {
    return in_array($user->type, ['developer', 'admin', 'operations']);
}
```

**SubscriptionController**:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->authorize('manage', Subscription::class);
}
```

The ability `manage` is not a method in `SubscriptionController`. The ability is for authorizing any method in the controller.

In the controllers, everything seems to work fine, i.e. if user is not authorized to add/edit/delete/view a Subscription, user gets a 403.

Now I would like to have certain menu items not show if the user is not authorized. However I can't get the `@can` directive to work.

```
@can('manage', Subscription::class)
    <li><a href="{{ route('subscriptions.index') }}">Subscriptions</a></li>
@endcan
```

That is, the menu item is always not shown (authorization always fails).

I am on Laravel 5.1.24

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `App\`, as in:

```
@can('manage', App\Subscription::class)
```

because the `$policies` array in `AuthServiceProvider` had `App\Subscription` as key.

Answer (score -1):

You must use role/premission to do specific object like this

```
@can('update-post', $post)
    <a href="/post/{{ $post->id }}/edit">Edit Post</a>
@endcan
```

I your case

```
@can('manage', Subscription::class->find(1))
   <li><a href="{{ route('subscriptions.index') }}">Subscriptions</a></li>
@endcan
```

Comment: I think using `App\Subscription::class` is enough because it only needs the class name so that it can get the policy name via the key in $policies of AuthServiceProvider

Comment: `Subscription::class->find(1) ` is not valid php.